# Login form vs Login Dialogue - Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, authentication

For a mobile phone application, would it be better to have a login form (I'm thinking would be the main form), which when you pass authentification would take you to the "MainPage" form, or a login dialog which opens before the main form and only allows the main form to open if it passes authentification?

My thoughts would be as a mobile app, if you log out, you don't necessarily want the entire app to close therefore having the login form as the main form, would be there (keeping the application alive) until you want to fully close it. And vice versa, with the login dialogue, since the main form is once you've logged in, when you log out you'd close that form as you don't have access to it, and therefore close the app.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is to broad and therefore not suitable for SO. 
besides you have already explained the main advantages of both approaches. Which one Will suite you more depends on your application and what you need from it.

Comment: My preferred approach is to have a TabControl with a login tab that shows first (only). Once the login is complete, the login tab is made invisible and other tabs show. You really don't want to mess with multiple forms in a mobile application.

Comment: @nolaspeaker do you have multiple forms open and show which one you need? Or do you close and open based on which tab is selected?

Comment: @WiliamCardoso My Android apps have only 1 form. That is the approach that causes the least problems. When you start a multi-device application, all the options use a tabcontrol except for the "blank application".

Comment: @nolaspeaker so does your code for all tabs only go on a single form? Could you provide link to where I can read abit about that way of doing it

Comment: @WiliamCardoso Yes it's all 1 form. In the Delphi IDE, choose from the main menu: File->New->Multi Device Application->Tabbed. This gets you to the basic application that you can build onto.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to make the main form with a TPageControl with some pages, the first will occupe the password and others the app things.
when you verify the password, you can pass to other tabs.